# How to bind a model of a overriden construtor

Tags: php, cakephp

I have two Model definition in my Cakephp app

**Customer.php**

```
class Customer extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'Customer';
    public function Customer($tableId){
    //.. code to assign a table name based on $tableId
    return parent::__construct("id", $this->useTable);
  }
}
```

and **CustomerOrder.php**

```
class CustomerOrder extends AppModel {

    var $name = 'CustomerOrder';
    var $belongsTo = array('Customer ' => array(
            'className' => 'Customer',
            'foreignKey' => 'customer_id'
        ));
}
```

Here Customer model would get its database tablename dynamically out of three mysql tables based from that constructor argument. When i query second model because Customer has overridden constructor i get mysql error because it cannot invoke right constructor in bind model.

is there additional parameter in $belongsTo to do this? or how can achieve this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: i think above is next to impossible because association models are converted into join queries that depends very little on model object, i might do it somehow by overriding methods of Model.php but that would be a trivial work

Answer (score 0):

I think you're constructing the class in another language way. In php, a constructor goes like

```
class Customer extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Customer';  //note: this line is really not necessary

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        //.. code to assign a table name based on $tableId
        return parent::__construct("id", $this->useTable, $ds);
    }
}
```

If you do that change, does is still give you that error?

(Btw, `$ds` is the DataSource connection name, you can check [the code](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/source-class-Model.html#641-750) for more info).

Comment: as per my knowledge php support both __construct() and java style constructor and when i do $model = new Customer("tableId") i get it work correctly, its only second model that is posing challenge, even if I override __construct() there is no way to pass $table param to this.